# redis save regex with backslash

Tags: go, redis

[image]

I am getting an issue after I get results from Redis.

The regexp is not correct parsing email addresses, is this a better way to handle this problem?

I  use Golang to write the Regex to Redis but the result is not I want.

Comment: Redis stores every value as a string, you need to serialize/deserialize all the values you store/retrieve in redis.

Comment: thanks for your advice

I found the regexp result with double backslash works well